# Want C# ASPX page to produce plain text rather than HTML

Tags: asp.net

I have a C# project in Visual Studio that produces an aspx page. The code I am editing is in `default.asp.cs`. When I build the project a file `default.aspx` is produced. This file looks something like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="CSRValidationConnector._Default" %>  
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div> 
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I make my web request most of this page comes back.

But I want the page to return only plain text and not any of this HTML. How do I configure things so that nothing is returned except what I add via `Response.Write` calls in `default.aspx.cs`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove all the HTML except:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="CSRValidationConnector._Default" %>
```

and in your codebehind Page_Load do a `Response.Write("String")`

Comment: But there is no default.aspx until AFTER I build. If I remove the code, won't those changes just get overwritten the next time I build? (Later) Ah, I see that it doesn't get overwritten. Silly me.

Comment: There should already be a Default.aspx page in your project. If there isn't, create a new one. Then you can do what cgreeno says.

Answer (score 4):

Response.ContentType is what you are looking for :)

```
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
```